# I erased Macintosh HD in disk utility, now I can't reinstall macOS Big Sur

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

So I wanted to reset my 2019 Macbook Pro, so I used CMD + R and went to disk utility and erased Macintosh HD... I then went to reinstall MacOS Big Sur and I got about halfway through the reinstallation but then it stopped and went to a prohibitory symbol with a black background and just states to go to Apple Support.

What have I done wrong, how do I fix this and get my Mac to reset properly?

Please any advice?

Comment: how is your disk formatted?  It should be APFS.

Answer (score 2):

If the recovery mode on your Mac won't let you install macOS, then the next trick is "Internet Recovery Mode". See this web page for a description of how to use it to reinstall your Mac's OS: https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/recovery-mode-internet-3636668/#internet%20recovery

The important thing to note here though, is that you need to be connected to the Internet in order to use it (the clue is in the name) and that a large download is involved, so it will take some time to start the recovery mode. I think it's about 12GB or so.

Comment: What is the difference between what the OP did and what you propose? What I mean is both methods download macOS from the internet.

Comment: Internet Recovery Mode boots from a recovery OS downloaded from the internet, and installs the OS from the downloaded data. Normal Recovery Mode boots from a recovery OS on the computer’s own drive, and installs the OS from the data on the drive. You can boot into Recovery Mode (as the OP says) by holding CMD+R, even without an internet connection. Internet Recovery Mode requires an internet connection

Comment: I have Big Sur installed and the output from `diskutil list` shows the `Recovery` volume is 610.8 MB in size. The OP erased the `Macintosh HD` volume. You state in your answer the installation files take about 12 GB. Do you still contend this data is on the OP's drive? If so, where on the drive?

Comment: Okay so I tried reinstalling one more time using CMD + R and it actually worked this time. So I didn't need to use internet recovery but thanks for your suggestion. However, my question is now what damage could I have done to my laptop by erasing Macintosh HD volume because everything is different now. I created a new account on my new resetted laptop. Now when I go into locations and go to Macintosh HD - Data then Users - then go into my user folder, I'm unable to access any of my folders it says it can't be opened because I don't have permission to see its contents, that and other things...